# Ionic: Custom ion list items

Tags: css, html, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am new to Ionic framework, I am trying to create an ion-list like in the picture, but I can't figure out how to use `item-thumbnail-right` and `item-avatar` in the one item with some stuff in the right corner and a pseudo footer like in the picture...
I tried this code:

```
<ion-list>
    <a class="item item-thumbnail-right" ng-repeat="activeOffer in activeOffers"
         ng-href="#/app/offers/{{activeOffer.offer.id}}">
        <img ng-src="{{siteRoot}}/upload/assets/img/media-support/{{activeOffer.mediaSupport.fileName}}">
        <div class="item item-avatar">
            <img ng-src="{{siteRoot}}/upload/assets/img/localbusiness/{{activeOffer.localBusiness.logo}}">
            <h2>{{activeOffer.localBusiness.label}}</h2>
            <p>{{activeOffer.localBusiness.description}}</p>
        </div>
        <h2>{{activeOffer.offer.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{activeOffer.offer.description}}</p>
    </a>
</ion-list>
```

But, I'm getting something ugly

[image: ion-list]

Comment: On SO people don't reply with complete solution neither you should expect from us the guys only guide developers to the write way with a small code some time.
"What ever you are struggling with that i've check and it's only belong to css part you need to understand how to use different classes properly the sequence of calling them so they should not override each others properties." BOL

Comment: @jemlifathi have u resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following example:

```
<ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar-right" ng-repeat="item in listingData.app" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/restaurant_category/{{item.rest_id}}">
    <img ng-src="{{item.logo}}">
    <img src="" style="float:left;width: 15px;height: 15px;">
    <h2>{{item.restaurant_name}}</h2>

    <p ng-repeat="cuisne in item.available_cuisine.cuisine">{{cuisne.name}}</p>
    <div class="row order-policy-time">

        <div class="col col-50">
            <p>delivers in 60 min</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-right">
            <p>collection in 30 min</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome-custom-icon">
        <span class="ti-angle-right"></span>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```